# Who is Soleil Moore, The Bone Clocks character?

Tags: character-analysis, david-mitchell, the-bone-clocks

In [The Bone Clocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bone_Clocks) by [David Mitchell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Mitchell_(author)) a character is introduced in the section 'Crispin Hershey’s Lonely Planet'.

The character named 'Soleil Moore' pops up three times:

- The Hay-on-Wye book fair where she gives Crispin her first collection of poetry
- A literary event in Shanghai where she gives Crispin another volume of poetry
- Bard College, USA where:

  > Crispin is then visited by Soleil Moore, whom he does not remember and who is horrified that he has not read the works she gave him. She tells him he is part of "the Script" and that humans are being used and abused by higher beings and she hoped that Crispin would help her publish her works so that they would become widespread knowledge. She then goes to Plan B and shoots Crispin, knowing that the murder will make her and her work infamous.

Nothing more is mentioned about Soleil in the book and it's never revealed whether her poetry actually does reveal what is going on.

Has there been any insight (whether from the author or speculation) as to who this character is?

Or, as is often the case with David Mitchell's characters, does She appear in any other stories ?